# Sonar Analysis issue for large project

Tags: sonarqube

I have a very large scale java project whose structuring is like this:

java->ROOT/A, java->ROOT/B, java->ROOT/C java->ROOT/...

Where A, B ,C are individual java projects. I tried to use sonar ant task in the build.xml of A, B ... but it was giving "org.sonar.squid.api.AnalysisException" error as the packages in A, B are something like package ROOT.A.xyz.

So I was bound to add the sonar ant task target in build.xml file of ROOT.

Now I am specifying the sonar.sources and sonar.binaries to java directory and including the exact project to be build using sonar.inclusions property i.e. A/B/C.

But the problem is though its analysing only files of A/B/C but its searcing from dependencies i.e. jar dependencies etc in entire project (ROOT) and is taking a lot of time. May I know what is the solution I can have were only dependencies of the respective project will be resolved.